# Testing Hibernate Mappings

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to map objects to a legacy schema which contains some ginormous tables via annotations (as XML files are so 2003). Since these classes are so large, yes I occasionally make an occasional typo, which Hibernate doesn't bother to tell me about until I try to run it.

Here's what I've tried:

**One: Setting hbm2ddl.auto to "validate":**

This causes the String values of the class to validate against `varchar(255)`. Since many of the column types in the database are `CHAR(n)`, this blows up. I would have to add the `columnDefinition="CHAR(n)"` to several hundred mappings.

**Two: Using Unitils.**

Importing these via Maven causes imports of dependency libraries which blow up other sections of code. Example: I'm using Hibernate 4.1, but Unitils imported Hibernate 3.2.5 and blew up a UserType.

So, is there another way to do this? I looked at the Unitils code to see if I could simply yank the sections I needed (I do that with apache-commons fairly often when I just need a single method), but that's not a simple task.

Hibernate is configured via a Spring application context.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1):

I would write tests against an in-memory database (HSQLDB, H2) using the Spring testing framework. You'll quickly see any mapping errors when you attempt to run queries against the tables.

The test class would look something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyTestConfig.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txMgr", defaultRollback=true)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // class body...
}
```

I would configure Hibernate to auto-deploy the tables as part of the tests.

Comment: Good answer, but not quite what I'm looking for. What I want is a way to test all my mappings at once, without having to write queries. It's looking like what I want isn't all that easy.

Comment: In my mind the only way to test your mappings is by executing queries. Unless you write a utility to check the annotations on you classes... that doesn't sound very straightforward.